# In this group ring, what does this mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm working with $R(G)$ a group ring where $R$ is a conmutative ring with $1_R$ and $G$ is a finite group $\{g_1,\dots,g_n\}$. Prove that:

> **(a)** $I=\{\sum_{i=1}^n a_ig_i\in R(G)|\sum_{i=1}^na_i=0_R \}$ is an ideal and that $R(G)/I$ is isomorphic to $R$.
>
> **(b)** $I$ is generated by $H=\{g-e|g\in G\}$, and that if $G=<\sigma>$ then $I=(\sigma -e)$.

I've already proved **(a)**, but I have no idea what to do for **(b)**, what does "$-e$" means? I thoug that maybe $H\subset G$, so that way $-e=e$, if we take $G$ to be an additive group, but that would also give us $g-e=g$, hence $H=G$, and that doesn't make sense to me. Whay am I suppose to do?

Comment: $g-e$ is the identity $e$ of $G$ subtracted (via the subtraction in $R(G)$) from $g$. So it's not the case that $H\subset G$. Observe that this is a natural example of the condition for membership in $I$: in particular, $n=2, a_1=-a_2=1$.

Comment: @KevinCarlson so is it like $g-e=g\;1_R-1_R e$?

Comment: Yes; seems clearer to write it as $1_Rg-1_R e$ though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put $x=\sum_{i=1}^n a_ig_i \in I$, i.e. $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i=0_R$.
Recall that the additive identity of $R(G)$ is $0_R e$.
Then $0_R e=(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i)e=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i e$.($*$)
Thus, $x=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i(g_i-e)$ by substituting the equation ($*$).

Comment: Ok with this, you're giving $I\subset H$, right? but I don't see why $x$ written like that is in the ring generated by $H$. The form of the elements in $(H)$ i think is $(g_k-e)\sum a_ig_i=g_k\sum a_ig_i - \sum a_ig_i$, (sorry if this is obvious but I obviously have issues with the representation)

Comment: Consider the map $\phi:R(G)\longrightarrow R$ by $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i(g_i-e) \longrightarrow \sum_{i=1}^n a_i$. You can check $\phi$ is a ring epimorphism with kernel $I$, which proves (a). Since $H$ is a subset in the ideal $I$, $(H)\subset I$, where $(H)$ is the ideal generated by H.
What I posed is the proof of "$I\subset (H)$". 
In addition to my answer before, $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i(g_i-e)=\sum_{i=1}^n( a_i e)(g_i-e)$.

Comment: Sorry,  $\phi: \sum_{i=1}^n a_ig_i\longrightarrow \sum_{i=1}^n a_i $

Answer (score 0):

If by $e$, you mean the multiplicative identity, then you can see that $I=\{\sum_{i=1}^n a_ig_i\in R(G)|\sum_{i=1}^na_i=0_R \}$ meaning $e$ is a root of $\sum_{i=1}^n a_ig_i$. So $I$ can be written as $\{<g-e>|g \in G\}$ because whatever belongs to $I$ will definitely have $e$ as its root.

Comment: Surely $e$ is not meant to denote the multiplicative identity of $R(G)$, rather than the identity of $G$.

Comment: In the original sentence I don't have a way to know what $e$ really is, but I was considering it to be the identity of $G$, like Kevin said, because the other multiplicative identity of $R$ is not usually written like that